# Is the Yahoo Finance API open?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have recently been looking after API:s to collect OHLC stock data and read about the yahoo finance API. After browsing the web for a while I was unable to find any documentation for their API but it seems like it still possible to collect the data through the pandas-datareader library. These lines of codes is taken from a youtube-video. However I was wondering if anyone knows if their API is still open and what this command is doing.

```
def get_data(ticker):
    try:
        stock_data = data.DataReader(ticker,
                                     'yahoo',
                                     START_DATE,
                                     END_DATE)
        stock_data.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
        return stock_data
    except RemoteDataError:
        print('No data found for {t}'.format(t=ticker))
```

Comment: Googled "yahoo finance api discontinued"; it seems to be discontinued as of 2017. It would also be useful for your question to show exactly how you're trying to use this code, in order to see where the error occurs

Comment: The short answer is `Yes`.  But the rumor is that it will be shut down sometimes? (no official)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the Yahoo API has gone, you may be able to find one that suits your needs from here: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/financial/apis?category=19968&keyword=stock

In terms of what the code is doing:

```
def get_data(ticker):
    try:
        # get data for the given `ticker` symbol, from Yahoo, between the two dates
        stock_data = data.DataReader(ticker,
                                     'yahoo',
                                     START_DATE,
                                     END_DATE)
        # Drop empty values from the data:
        stock_data.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)

        return stock_data
    except RemoteDataError:
        print('No data found for {t}'.format(t=ticker))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my search shows that the Yahoo Finance API was shut down in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The **Official** Yahoo Finance API was closed in 2017, however there are unofficial versions. The most popular is [this](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/yahoo-finance1), hosted on RapidAPI, however I believe you have to pay for some functionalities. I would recommend using an alternative like [Alpha Vantage](https://pypi.org/project/alpha-vantage/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that API https://rapidapi.com/telescopeanalytics-hl8pcoeL44o/api/telescope-stocks-options-price-charts/. This API provide an access to actual information from stock exchanges worldwide. It supports getting information about emitents and the history of share price changes.

Example:

```
import requests

url = "https://telescope-stocks-options-price-charts.p.rapidapi.com/stocks/AAPL"

querystring = {"modules":"assetProfile,summaryProfile,price"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "telescope-stocks-options-price-charts.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```